# What C headers for directory traversal are process safe in Linux?

Tags: c, linux, cgi, pid

I'm currently using dirent.h and ftw.h for directory traversal at my CGI website 100% programmed in C. I am not sure if they are process safe; would various users interfere with each other while on my site ?

Which functions would you recommend for this purpose ?

Comment: What do you mean by process safe?

Comment: If you mean they are safe to use simultaneously from multiple processes, yes, they are.

Comment: Yes, run multiple processes simultaneously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is safe for multiple processes to, for example, use `ftw()` to walk the same directory tree at the same time.

**However** it is not necessarily safe for one process to be walking the directory tree while another process is *updating* the same directory tree structure (ie adding, removing or renaming directories).  If you have this situation, then you will need to make your CGI processes use an `flock()` advisory lock (you could just have a single empty lockfile in the root of the shared directory tree; processes that want to walk the tree have to take a shared lock on that lockfile, and processes that want to alter the tree have to take an exclusive lock on the lockfile).

Answer (score 0):

You probably mean "thread-safe" instead of process-safe. All libc calls are process-safe on Linux as processes (normally) live in separate memory spaces.
On the other hand, `readdir` is not thread-safe, as it keeps an internal static storage for the context. Use `readdir_r` in that case (the _r means reentrant). The other functions in `dirent.h` are reentrant by default.

Comment: He seems to actually mean *process* safe, given the context of worrying about different users running the same CGI script (which would usually mean different processes, unless FastCGI is involved).

Comment: Yes, process safe. Just normal CGI, not FastCGI.

Comment: Well in that case, no reason to worry, as all libc functions are process-safe.
Of course, users could still interfere with each other if one process is writing a file and another process is reading the same file, but that's not what you're doing.